"undefined reference to av···@···"ffmpeg error，when i cross compile opencv4.5.3 which include ffmpeg lib
I'm working on an embedded deployment project, doing object detection work on a real-time video stream. So I have to port my C++ inference program to the RKNN1808 platform. I compile this program with the CMake tool, but I can't finish my work because OpenCV lib can't be compiled correctly.
To FFmpeg, my configure commend is following:
./configure --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu- --target-os=linux --arch=aarch64 --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg  --enable-shared

Then I am gonna to show you the FFmpeg version:
libavutil      56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100

Next, I use following commend to build the CMake project:
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -D CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-lpthread -ldl -D ENABLE_PIC=ON -D WITH_1394=OFF -D WITH_ARAVIS=OFF -D WITH_ARITH_DEC=ON -D WITH_ARITH_ENC=ON -D WITH_CLP=OFF -D WITH_CUBLAS=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_CUFFT=OFF -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10=OFF -D WITH_HALIDE=OFF -D WITH_HPX=OFF -D WITH_IMGCODEC_HDR=ON -D WITH_IMGCODEC_PXM=ON -D WITH_IMGCODEC_SUNRASTER=ON -D WITH_INF_ENGINE=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_ITT=OFF -D WITH_JASPER=ON -D WITH_JPEG=ON -D WITH_LAPACK=ON -D WITH_LIBREALSENSE=OFF -D WITH_NVCUVID=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS=OFF -D WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL_SVM=OFF -D WITH_OPENEXR=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_OPENMP=OFF -D WITH_OPENNNI=OFF -D WITH_OPENNNI2=OFF -D WITH_OPENVX=OFF -D WITH_PNG=OFF -D WITH_PROTOBUF=OFF -D WITH_PTHREADS_PF=ON -D WITH_PVAPI=OFF -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_QUIRC=OFF  -D WITH_TBB=OFF -D WITH_TIFF=ON -D WITH_VULKAN=OFF -D WITH_WEBP=ON -D WITH_XIMEA=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../CrossCompileResult  -D WITH_GTK=OFF  -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF ..

Following is the output about FFmpeg:
--   Video I/O:
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)


After building the CMake project, I compiled this project with comment 【make -j16. After not so long time, I got the Error:
[ 49%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_annotation
[ 49%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts_tags.cpp.o
[ 49%] Built target opencv_annotation
[ 49%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_visualisation
/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.58, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.58, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.56, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/midsummer/Tool/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libswscale.so.5, needed by ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_init_packet@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_get_riff_video_tags@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_send_packet@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_receive_packet@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_get_mov_video_tags@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder_by_name@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_name@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_transfer_data@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avio_open@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_sub_q@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_packet_free@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_flush_buffers@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `sws_getContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_receive_frame@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_write_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_seek_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `sws_freeContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_dict_set@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_descriptor_get_by_name@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_5'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_dict_parse_string@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_frame_get_buffer@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_freep@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_free_context@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_default_get_format@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_init@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_free@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_get_buffer@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_guess_sample_aspect_ratio@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_new_stream@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_constraints_free@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_ctx_create_derived@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_frame_unref@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_buffer_unref@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_write_trailer@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_packet_rescale_ts@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_get_by_name@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_send_frame@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_hw_config@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_buffer_ref@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_dict_get@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_free@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_codec_is_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_lockmgr_register@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_packet_alloc@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_create_derived@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_send_packet@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_alloc@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_log_set_level@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_image_get_buffer_size@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_open2@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_codec_is_encoder@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_guess_format@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_image_fill_arrays@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_receive_packet@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_5'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_tag@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_get_hwframe_constraints@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_ctx_create@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_codec_iterate@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_log_set_callback@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_parameters_copy@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_pix_fmt_to_codec_tag@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwframe_ctx_alloc@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_mallocz@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_find_input_format@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_dict_free@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_hw_frames_parameters@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_get_type_name@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_frame_free@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_bsf_init@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_close@LIBAVCODEC_58'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name@LIBAVUTIL_56'
../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.3: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_context_defaults3@LIBAVCODEC_58'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/build.make:89: bin/opencv_visualisation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3357: apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 49%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
[ 49%] Built target opencv_calib3d
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_ts.a
[ 50%] Built target opencv_ts
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2


I don't know what's wrong with it, it has confused me for a few days, I real hope someone can help me solve the prob.
I promise the the FFmpeg version match the version of OpenCV strictly, promising the PKG_CONFIG_PATH is right.
I have tried many method like changing OpenCV version orFFmpeg version, recompiling the FFmpeg, changing PKG_CONFIG_PATH, coping FFmpeg PC file from:
/usr/local/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig
to:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
I hope somebody can give some idea about how to solve this problem.

I got same issue (ffmpeg error) at first.
Try the following install & update below steps:
Update ubuntu package list and upgrade packages
apt update && apt -y upgrade

Install packages to compile OpenCV 4.4
apt install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config \
libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libpng-dev \
    ffmpeg libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libxine2-dev \
    libv4l-dev v4l-utils \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-dri libgtkgl2.0-dev libgtkglext1-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev gfortran libeigen3-dev \
    python3 python3-dev python3-numpy


sorry，we have the same target，but different from the procedure.All my opencv conponent have to installed by cross-compile. which have to use cross compile tools but not install opencv4.4 that use apt directly.thanks anyway.
